# obtener todos los datos de un array y exportarlo a csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola estoy pegado con algo, pasa que estoy utilizando jquery ajax y a traves de una url recibo los datos en json donde los estoy metiendo a un array para luego pasar esos datos a un archivo tipo csv, pero siempre me toma solo la ultima fila no logro  almacenar todas las filas mi codigo es el siguiente;

```js
function download(){

 var headers = {
  nombre: 'Nombres'.replace(/,/g, ''), // remove commas to avoid errors
  apellidos: 'Apellidos',
  cargo: 'Cargo',
  usuario: 'Usuario',
  tipousuario: 'Tipo Usuario'
 };

 var url = "localhost/json/usuarios.php"; //SERVER
 $.getJSON(url,  function(data){

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

   itemsNotFormatted = [
    {
     nombre: data[i].nombre,
     apellidos: data[i].apellidos,
     cargo: data[i].desc_cargo,
     usuario: data[i].usuario,
     tipousuario: data[i].destipousuario
    }
   ]; 

   console.log(itemsNotFormatted); 

  }

  var itemsFormatted = [];

  //Formato del datos
  itemsNotFormatted.forEach((item) => {

   itemsFormatted.push({
    nombre: item.nombre.replace(/,/g, ''), // remove commas to avoid errors,
    apellidos: item.apellidos.replace(/,/g, ''),
    cargo: item.cargo.replace(/,/g, ''),
    usuario: item.usuario,
    tipousuario: item.tipousuario
   });

  });

  var filename = 'usuarios'; // or 'my-unique-title'

  exportCSVFile(headers, itemsFormatted, filename); // call the exportCSVFile() function to process the JSON and trigger the download


 });

}
```

y el archivo al descargar los datos, como mencione no me carga todas las filas si no que solo la ultima por lo que necesito obtenerlos todos dentro del archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con cada iteración del ciclo, estás reemplazando el valor del arreglo `itemsNotFormatted`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    // Estás reemplazando el contenido del arreglo
    itemsNotFormatted = [
        {
            nombre: data[i].nombre,
            apellidos: data[i].apellidos,
            cargo: data[i].desc_cargo,
            usuario: data[i].usuario,
            tipousuario: data[i].destipousuario
        }
    ];  
    // En la impresión de los valores se ve bien (en la iteración),
    // ya que imprimís únicamente el valor que se agregó
    console.log(itemsNotFormatted); 

}
```

Lo correcto es hacer un push al arreglo para agregar un nuevo objeto al final del mismo:

```
itemsNotFormatted.push({
    nombre: data[i].nombre,
    apellidos: data[i].apellidos,
    cargo: data[i].desc_cargo,
    usuario: data[i].usuario,
    tipousuario: data[i].destipousuario
});
```

Comment: El ejemplo que puse era de un tutorial, que ni siquiera tenia definiciones, por lo cual fui adaptando mi código a ese mismo, según como tu lo mencionas, me a dado resultado, te lo agradezco